# How to add an Image from Blob in a Cell from sqlite?

Tags: excel, sqlite, blob, jxl

I want to use my database that contains string data and an image to convert them to excel. Then, I have stored in my sqlite a series of data string and an image (Blob) but I can not understand how to display the image in an excel cell. The database is loaded correctly but it is difficult for me to reconvert my Blob (I have it stored as a byte array) and show it. I'm using the JXL library. I hope you can help me, Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
private void openActivity() {
    //add your further process after giving permission or to download images from remote server.
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper ( this );
    dbHelper.insertData ();

    final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getuser ();

    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ();
    String csvFile = "LectorDeEstados.xls";

    File directory = new File ( sd.getAbsolutePath () );
    //create directory if not exist
    if (!directory.isDirectory ()) {
        directory.mkdirs ();
    }
    try {

        //file path
        File file = new File ( directory, csvFile );
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings ();
        wbSettings.setLocale ( new Locale ( "en", "EN" ) );
        WritableWorkbook workbook;
        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook ( file, wbSettings );

        WritableSheet sheet = null;


        sheet = workbook.createSheet ( "Lectura de estados - Cooperativa", 0 );



            sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 0, 0, "ID" ) );
            sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 1, 0, "Nombre" ) );
            sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 2, 0, "Domicilio" ) );
            sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 3, 0, "Número de Medidor" ) );
            sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 4, 0, "Ultima Lectura" ) );
            sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 5, 0, "Foto" ) );

            if (cursor.moveToFirst ()) {
                do {
                    String title = cursor.getString ( cursor.getColumnIndex ( "id" ) );
                    String email = cursor.getString ( cursor.getColumnIndex ( "name" ) );
                    String mobile = cursor.getString ( cursor.getColumnIndex ( "address" ) );
                    String mobile2 = cursor.getString ( cursor.getColumnIndex ( "medidor" ) );
                    String mobile1 = cursor.getString ( cursor.getColumnIndex ( "nueva" ) );
                  //  byte[] mobile3 = cursor.getBlob ( cursor.getColumnIndex ( "foto" ) );
                    byte[] mobile3 = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex ("foto"));



                    int i = cursor.getPosition () + 1;

                    sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 0, i, title ) );
                    sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 1, i, email ) );
                    sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 2, i, mobile ) );
                    sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 3, i, mobile2 ) );
                    sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 4, i, mobile1 ) );


                    sheet.addCell ( new Label ( 5, i, mobile3 )  );

                } while (cursor.moveToNext ());
            }

            //closing cursor
            cursor.close ();
            workbook.write ();
            workbook.close ();
            Toast.makeText ( getApplication (), " EXCEL ha sido Exportado a la Memoria Interna del Dispositivo ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();


        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `WritableWorkbook` and `WritableSheet` are not `apache poi` classes but `jxl` ones. So please clarify what library you are using and do tagging the question correct.

Comment: Sorry! you are rigth, i´m using jxl!

Comment: Then edit your tags accordingly.